# The wave equation with a boundary condition that turns on at $t=0$

Tags: waves, boundary-conditions

Consider the wave equation in 1 spatial dimension (in units where $c=1$)
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u(t,x)}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u(t,x)}{\partial x^2} = 0 \ .
$$
Now suppose that the solution is $u(t,x)=0$ for all $t<0$. Then suddenly at $t=0$ a boundary condition gets enforced at $x=x_0$
$$
u(x_0, t) = \Theta(t) b(t,x_0) \ ,
$$
for some function $b$.

Can progress be made towards a solution for such a boundary condition? For concreteness, I would like to consider the behaviour of the solution $u(t,x)$ for $t>0$ and  $x>x_0$ (only to the right of the boundary condition).

For $t>0$ and $x>x_0$ the solution should have the standard form $u(t,x) = F(x - t) + G(x + t)$ for some functions $F$ and $G$.

My guess is that $G=0$ should be true for this set-up (*ie.* no incoming wave for $x>x_0$), since the disturbance caused by the boundary condition should probably cause only an *outgoing* wave (described just by $F$, a function of the retarded time $t-x$).

My second guess is that $F$ is probably proportional to a $\Theta(t - x)$ for $x>x_0$, since the outgoing wave needs to take some time to arrive at the point $x >x_0$

Is this true? and How to see this?

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind for t<0. if $u(x,t) = 0$ for all x when t<0, then $u(x,t) = 0$ for all x and t

Comment: @mmesser314 Wouldn't that be true only for $b=0$?

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

See D'Alembert's solution for the 1D wave equation. It will provide the solution. But you will need two initial conditions: u(x,0) and u'(x,0) since the wave equation is second order. You will find that F=G and that you have an additional term due to u'(x,0).  u is the initial displacement at t=0 and u'(x,0) is the initial speed of displacement at t=0.

See my https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340085346

which shows what is required to cancel the backward wave.